# IE 11 browser Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template

Tags: angularjs

Getting error Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template  in IE browser, while refresh the page

Comment: In my case it is not access denied. It is only happens when I refresh the page in IE-11 browser.